# Oauth for authorization JWT for authentication for an app using DRF and cloud functions

Tags: google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, oauth, google-cloud-functions, jwt

I'm building a web app with Wagtail as back-end, running on app engine, cloud functions doing micro-services and triggered via http.
I want to let my users register and authorize using social apps and classic login-password and get a JWT token from Wagtail App. Then, the token will be used to authenticate users both on cloud functions and Wagtail back-end.
How do I provide the user with JWT tokens if he/she authorizes with OAuth?
Is my approach correct? Any suggestions on how this should be done in the proper way?

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement a [custom authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) by [creating custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) on your backend.  A full discussion for how to implement this is outside the scope of a single Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @doug-stevenson, that's bad news. I was hoping my task is rather common. Thanks for the links.

Comment: It is somewhat common, but it still requires work to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found so far is to use firebase auth. In python I verify token like that:

```
from firebase_admin import auth

decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
uid = decoded_token['uid']
```